# swift Could not cast value of type

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, generics

I have many TableViewCells, one is base class

```
BaseTableViewCell<T: BaseTableViewItem>: UITableViewCell{
    public var item: T!
}
```

and another is subClass like

```
ATableViewCell: BaseTableViewCell<ATableViewItem>

BTableViewCell: BaseTableViewCell<BTableViewItem>
```

ATableViewItem and BTableViewItem  is subclass of BaseTableViewItem

problem is

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: item.cellIdentifier)
   (cell as! BaseTableViewCell).item.title = "title"
   return cell!;
}
```

and crash in `cell as! BaseTableViewCell`

> Could not cast value of type 'Example.ATableViewCell' (0x1078453f0) to 'Example.BaseTableViewCell

how can i do ?

ps:
I do this because i want to improve my project https://github.com/JavenZ/ZJTableViewManager, in this project, when i use custom cell, always write code like `let item = self.item as! ZJTextItem`, i think It's a little tricky to use. 
so i try to use generic. It seems that I haven't found a good way. you can see demo in ZJTableViewManager.
I'm very sorry that my English is poor and I can't express myself clearly

Comment: In your example there’s ATableViewCell and in the error ATextFieldCell. Misprint or the problem?

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen  It‘s misprint, sorry, I fixed this description error

Comment: But how do you cast something that makes use of generics? I think you would be much better of with a protocol here than inheritance.

Comment: You can cast a subclass to a superclass, but in this case generics have been introduced which means that your classes are not compatible. `ATableViewCell<ATableViewItem>` is not a subclass of `BaseTableViewCell<BaseTableViewItem>`. You could cast `ATableViewCell<BaseTableViewItem>` to `BaseTableViewCell<BaseTableViewItem>`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to cast a subclass to its superclass, which is impossible. You can downcast (casting a superclass to its subclass) because the subclass has the same properties as its superclass, and thus all the information of an instance of the superclass can find a place in the instance of the subclass. However, the subclass can have more information in it than the superclass, so all of its information might not be able to find a place in the superclass.

I also don't see why this is necessary. Anywhere the type of an object is specified as one class, its subclasses can be used in its place. If you need to use an overridden method of the superclass from the subclass, you can always use the `super` keyword. I don't see why upcasting (subclass to superclass, what you are doing) is necessary. If you can clarify a reason, maybe I can help more, but you should avoid upcasting if it is unnecessary.

Comment: I think it's possible to cast a subclass to its superclass, you can see my demo in
https://github.com/JavenZ/ZJTableViewManager  ZJTableViewManager.swift file, line 124, it worked fine.

Comment: I do this because i don't want to write `let item = self.item as! ZJTextItem` every time in custom cell, so i try to use generic. can you help me ? I'm very sorry that my English is poor and I can't express myself clearly

Comment: I'll definitely look into it, but I apologize if I am not able to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can only cast things that are strict subclass/superclasses of each other.

For example, if I have

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell { ... }
```

then I can say

```
let cell: UITableViewCell = MyCell()  // Swift knows that MyCell inherits from `UITableViewCell`
```

and I can say

```
var someCell: UITableViewCell

...

let myCell = someCell as? MyCell  // Swift knows that this might work
```

but you can't say something like:

```
let s: String = someCell
```

These types just aren't related.

In your case you have introduced generics, so even though the basic classes are in an inheritance chain, the addition of the generic variation means that are aren't compatible.  I can't say something like:

```
let cell: ATableViewCell<Int> = ATableViewCell<String>()
```

They just aren't the same.

To do so would violate the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Consider a simple generic class:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    var item:T

    init(item: T) {
        self.item = item
    }
}


let a = SomeClass<Int>(item: 10)

print(a.item+10)   // Prints 20

let b = SomeClass<String>(item: "10")

print(b.item+10)  // Compiler error - You can't add a string and an integer
```

You can see that I need to know the specific *type* that is used with the generic in order to understand what operations are possible.  I can't assign an instance of `SomeClass<String>` to a variable declared as `SomeClass<Int>`; the set of valid operations are incompatible.

You could perhaps use a protocol with an associated type and then use type erasure so that you could use that protocol with a subclass, but at some point you need to know the concrete type of cell you are dealing with in a particular row and so you are going to need to cast the result of `dequeueReusableCell` to that concrete class.  Generics and protocols probably just make things more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. I do this because i want to improve my project https://github.com/JavenZ/ZJTableViewManager  In this project, when I use custom cell, always write code like let item = self.item as! ZJTextItem, i think It's a little tricky to use. So I try to use generic. It seems that I haven't found a good way. You can run demo in `ZJTableViewManager`. I'm very sorry that my English is poor and can't express question clearly and politely.